# Deleting empty folders in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Outlook 2013 at work and I organise my mails in folders/subfolders base on topics and work items. Hence, I create many folders/subfolders during the year.

I also use the built in archiving to move last year's mails to a new data file (I have one for each year).

The problem is that Outlook creates the folder anyway in archiving data files even if the folder has no email to archive. This result in creating many empty folders and lots of scrolling when I want to get to some folder.

Is there any way to search and delete these folder; i.e., an option or command line that gets and deletes empty folder (empty folders are the folders that do not contain any item or any other folder)?

P.S., I know I can do it manually by going through each folder, see if it is empty or not and delete it if it is empty. I want an easier way because I have more important things to do in my time :)

Answer (score 2):

[Refer to This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/exchange/en-US/e9f44fd4-9c6f-45f2-83cf-e3bb800548ca/exchange-archive-delete-empty-folders)

You will see that it is not possible to do so without PowerShell and code etc.
Following the answer proposed in the link, you can then use the script [here](http://www.xipher.dk/WordPress/?p=255).

**But wait**, [this](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderDeleteEmpty/#.VCOO6RYp3DM) is a free add-in to delete empty folders. It sounds promising.